# How do I change the default browser in Windows 11?

Tags: browser, windows-11, windows-11-preview

In Windows 11 (currently in preview, build 22000.51), how do I set the default browser? In the previous version Windows 10, I could select a default app for web browser but now everything is by file type or link type.

I use Firefox for example, and it asks me to set it as the default browser. When I try to make it the default browser, it opens the Default apps settings. I scrolled down to Firefox and associated it with everything there but the MAILTO type at the bottom. It still does not consider itself as the default browser.

[image: Firefox link types]

[image: Firefox default]

Answer (score 3):

After going back and forth in the settings, it appears there is a bug (in preview build 22000.51 at least). There were two file types that were not shown previously, `.htm` and `.html`. After setting these, Firefox is now the default browser.

I tested all file types and the crucial ones for Firefox to consider itself the default browser were `.htm`, `.html`, `HTTP`, and `HTTPS`.

[image: Firefox link types missing]

## Conclusion

So in conclusion the answer is to go to **Settings** > **Apps** > **Default apps** > scroll to and select your installed browser of choice (Firefox, Chrome, etc.) and associate the file types or link types:

- .htm
- .html
- HTTP
- HTTPS
- ...and any others you wish to open with your preferred browser

[image: Firefox default current]

Comment: Can this be done using PowerShell or any Windows Command Line setup?