# How do I change the default browser to open .htm and .html files in Windows 11

Tags: firefox, browser, file-association, windows-11, default-settings

I know this has been asked and answered in the past, BUT the other articles show that these file types should be able to be set in the settings through APPS>DEFAULT APPS>FIREFOX but Firefox and even searching through the "Enter a file type or link type." search box doesn't give any results.

[image: Missing the .htm file type defaults]

[image: Missing the .html file type defaults]

Has Windows 11 updated since, or is something else going on?
I'm very experienced with windows and the in's and out's of using a PC. I'm building a web project and its a pain to need to specify the browser through the context menu each time I need to open an html file. I can't even go as far as set it to VS Code.

The defaults are currently opening them in Edge, but they're not listed in Edge's defaults list either.

**My Windows Specifications:**

- Edition: Windows 11 Home
- Version: 21H2
- Installed on: 10/‎5/‎2021
- OS build: 22000.469
- Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.469.0

**Update:**
[John](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john) pointed out for me to check "Choose defaults by file type" at the bottom of APPS>DEFAULT APPS, though I'm unfortunately having the same issue there.

[image: "We couldn't find anything to show here"]

Comment: Have you looked in Settings, Apps, Default Apps, scroll down and select Choose defaults by file type. Both .htm and .html are selectable .  I only use Edge on my Windows 11 machines but the select an app function does work.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Though after checking it's the same issue, it's not finding the associations for .htm or .html "We couldn't find anything to show here. Double check your search criteria."

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1701342/how-do-i-set-another-program-as-jpg-default-in-windows-11/1701523#1701523) seems similar. Have you tried to simply reinstall Firefox? No; Windows 11 hasn’t been updated and it’s absolutely positively still possible to change the default browser on Windows 11

Comment: The file association defaults for .htm and .html aren't displaying anywhere, not only in Firefox, it's not even listed in Edge, or Brave's defaults lists. I can try reinstalling Firefox but I don't see how that would fix this particular issue. Although the question does seem really similar, so I'll try getting rid of Brave (don't use it now), and reinstalling Firefox. Then I'll update.

Comment: Maybe repair your Windows 11 OS.  Working fine here (Windows 11 Pro).

Answer (score 0):

I went to uninstall Brave as it was not used, and re-install Firefox. I uninstalled Brave first, then checked again for the defaults for .htm/.html and they are working now.

I can't say I understand what happened, but I guess something was conflicting and causing issues.

Problem solved.

Comment: There was a bug a while ago when I used [Windows 11 preview build 22000.51](https://superuser.com/a/1660208/403203). Disclaimer: the link is to my answer on a similar question. The trick is to go back and forth in the settings menu between **Apps > Default apps**, or **Default Apps > Firefox**. For some reason the `.htm` and `.html` options are not listed _sometimes_. I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft still hasn't fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Win+R`, type `regedit`, go to `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.AssocFile.HTM\shell\opennew\command`

Edit `(Default)`, Change `"C:\Program Files (x86)\internet explorer\iexplore.exe" %1` into `"your browser path" %1`

Reference:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-change-default-app-for-the-html-files/b38946e5-2399-4899-8523-5d1c5c0d044e